# Python : font_name and bold property not working together in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`. If i use `font_name` and `bold` property together then bold property doesn't work.If i remove `font_name` property then `bold` property works.Anyone tell me where i am making mistake?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window

class User(Screen):
    pass


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
User:
    BoxLayout:

        Button:
            font_name: 'Verdana'
            bold : True
            text: 'Font name and bold not working together'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because the given *font_name* does not contain Verdana bold.

## Solution 1

Replace

```
font_name: 'Verdana'
```

with

```
font_name: './data/fonts/Verdana/verdanab.ttf'
```

## Solution 2

Use *config* to override the default fonts, Roboto

### kv file

```
Button:
    bold : True
    text: 'Font name and bold not working together'
```

### Python code

```
from kivy.config import Config

default_font = Config.get('kivy', 'default_font')
print(default_font)

fonts = [
    'Verdana', './data/fonts/Verdana/verdana.ttf',
    './data/fonts/Verdana/verdanai.ttf',
    './data/fonts/Verdana/verdanab.ttf',
    './data/fonts/Verdana/verdanaz.ttf'
]
Config.set('kivy', 'default_font', fonts)
default_font = Config.get('kivy', 'default_font')
print(default_font)
```

## Download Verdana Fonts

The Verdana fonts that is usedin this example is from [AllBestFonts](https://allbestfonts.com/verdana/)

## Output

[image: Img01 - Solution 1]
[image: Img02 - Solution 2]